# Cross-site Forms Authentication can't get Identity Name

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I created one webapi app and other mvc app, and they are under same domain ,i create a forms authtication credentials in the mvc app web.config,and authentication works well only in mvcapp. But the requirement and problem is that When i am login in, i want the webapi app to share same credentials with mvc app(different sub domain),so that only the mvcapp (login in) have access to webapi app, I see tutorials like [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb0zx8fc.aspx),but i cant get the IdentityName when i'm debugging the webapi app.  this is my mvcapp webconfig below.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Project/Login" timeout="60" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" protection="All" path="/" domain="samedomin.com" >
    <credentials passwordFormat="SHA1">
      <user name="username" password="35bf0f7bd4c19a5d69f513ab8b08b7cf500d8a98"/>
    </credentials>
  </forms>
</authentication>
```

**Update**:the cookie exists when i put the webapi GET requested URL into address field and access it directly ,but in the mvc app use $.get to it still show 401 (Unauthorized)..someone help~~

Comment: the cookie exists when i put the webapi GET requested URL into address field and access it directly ,but in the mvc app use $.get still show 401 (Unauthorized)..someone help~~

Comment: Make sure Cookies authentication is enabled in Web API project `app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());`

Comment: @Paresh I didn't add this but i solved this by add AllowAnonymous Attribute on the webapi controller ,but i'm still trying to figure out why it takes effect.